# JS;D3 Barchart UNDEFINED Error : Uncaught TypeError, Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, d3.js, undefined

Being new to javascript I was trying to do a barchart with D3. 
This barchart uses a csv file with multiple data ( 3 colums) and should update itself when one changes the input data with a slider

But I have ran into an error that I can't resolve: 
TypeError: bars is undefined

Could somenone help me find a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you are calling `loadData` (which has an asynchronous call `d3.csv(...)`) and immediately `setupLstup` in the `setup` function.

The `setupLstup` requires `lstupData` wich is set by the callback in `onDataLoaded`.

Without going deeper into the code, maybe moving the call to `setupLstup` into `onDataLoaded` (and of course removing it from the `setup` function), may already solve the problem:

```
function onDataLoaded(data) {
    lstupData = data;
    setupLstup();
    graphLstup(2019);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a little bit as I now see the axis with the labels, but the bars of the chart don't seem to appear though. What do think is wrong ?

Comment: This is hard to answer if I don't see the data you pass to the graph. For more complex questions I would recommend to create a running example on ex. jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co otherwise its really hard to guess what may be wrong